# Why can't I pin the presenting toolbar of "Skype for Business" in a Citrix VDI?

Tags: vdi, citrix-receiver, skype-for-business

When presenting screen via Skype for Business, the toolbar says "Pinned" when i hover the mouse over it. But it seems disabled, below are my details. Kindly help.

**Citrix Receiver 4.4.1000.16**

**VDI details:**

Windows 7 Professional Service Pack1
Skype for Business 2015

[image: Pinned and Disabled]

Comment: Does it give any error messages? Are you able to provide a screenshot? Does the behaviour occur locally as well?

Comment: No error messages, just disabled and says 'Pinned' when i hover. Attached snapshot.

Comment: This is happening for me in a Virtual Environment. The PIN is grayed out in my case and I cannot hide the toolbar.  Microsoft says it is by design in a Citrix or VDI environment. Why by design, nobody knows. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9738998d-4672-4f8f-b17f-a645fe8cd9d1/not-getting-sharing-toolbar-in-skype-for-business-to-hide-on-vdi-system?forum=sfbfr

Comment: Yes, but it works fine with VmWare client.